# Can't access a child node in HTML

Tags: html, nodes

I'm working on an exercice that deals with nodes. I'm supposed to replace the first child of a string and the second element. The first child, changing "this is" to "very", but changing "special" to "ordinary" doesn't seem to work.
Would someone explain this to me?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.red { color : #FF0000 }
.big { font-size: xx-large }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function f(){
    node=document.getElementById('i1');
    node.firstChild.nodeValue='Very ';
    node.childNodes[1].nodeValue=" ordinary ";
}
</script>
</head>
<body class='big'>
<h5>Making changes</h5>
<p id='i1'>This is <em>special</em> <span class='red'>text</span>.</p>
<p onclick='f();'>Click to change the paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the `nodeValue` of an HTMLElement. [You cannot do this as the `nodeValue` for an HTMLElement (your `em` element) is `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).

You will need to set the `textContent`, `innerText`, or `innerHTML` instead.

```
node.childNodes[1].textContent = " ordinary ";
```

Why does this work for `node`'s `firstChild` (changing "This is" to "Very")? It is a `textNode`, and therefore you can get and set its `nodeValue`.

Comment: Thank you, thorough and concise explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Here you're calling chillNodes[1], so it's the second element in the list chillNodes. To get the first child, you should call `chillNodes[0]`.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp

Comment: childNodes[0] calls "this is", and is already accessed by firstChild.

Comment: Oups, you're totally right. Did you try .textContent instead of .nodeValue ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.red { color : #FF0000 }
.big { font-size: xx-large }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function f(){
    node=document.getElementById('i1');
    node.firstChild.nodeValue='Very ';
    node.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue=" ordinary ";
}
</script>
</head>
```

Because `<em>`is another child.
(https://jsfiddle.net/h8vmf0d6/)